# How to schedule the Apex class for every 90 minutes?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have tried to execute my scheduler class from anonymous window to schedule it every 90 minutes but it is only scheduling for 1 hr.

```
TokenScheduler testobj = new TokenScheduler();
String cronexpression = '0 59+31 * * * ?';
System.schedule('TokenScheduler', cronexpression, testobj);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on the Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) goes into more detail about what is/isn't possible in the "Using the System.Schedule Method" section.

Cron cannot do this in a single expression, but you also do not need 16 separate schedule calls. 2 should suffice because you can use the special character `/` to specify an increment in the hours part of the expression.

Assuming that you start at midnight, your execution times (seconds, minutes, hours) would be:

- 0 0 0
- 0 30 1
- 0 0 3
- 0 30 4
- 0 0 6
- 0 30 7
- etc...

This is easily broken out into 2 patterns:

- hour is 0, 3, 6, etc...
- minute is 30, and hour is 1, 4, 7, etc...

In both cases, the hour is always incrementing by 3

So you can distill this into 2 cron expressions
`0 0 0/3 * * ?`
`0 30 1/3 * * ?`

Comment: So do I need to use any one of the above expressions? i.e. 0 0 0/3 * * *
0 30 1/3 * * *. Please let me know. I haven't worked on scheduled jobs. Please hlp.

Comment: @Rene As my answer says, you need to use both.

Comment: How do I use it as a cron expression ? It is not allowing me to execute as it is such a big expression.

Comment: I am getting Line: 227, Column: 1
System.StringException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented. exception when trying to execute both the expressions. Please help @Derek F

Comment: @Rene I've updated my answer to (hopefully) address that error. The final `*` changed to a `?`. I thought that `*` wasn't "specifying" a value, but it appears I was mistaken on that front. As the documentation I linked states, `?` is the "has no value" value.

Comment: Thanks @Derek but it is scheduling 2 jobs. and the second job is exactly scheduled at 90minutes from the submit time. So my question is how to stop the first job which is after 30mins. Please clarify.

Comment: @Rene The main point in my answer was that _you cannot do this in a single job_. Having 2 jobs to do what you want here is _required_. It is only by having the two jobs that you are able to run your code on a 90 minute interval (job1 will run and finish, then 90 minutes later job2 will run and finish. Then job1 gets run 90 minutes after that, and so on).

Comment: Thanks @Derek I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try with below.

```
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 1', '0 30 1 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 2', '0 0 3 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 3', '0 30 4 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 4', '0 0 6 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 5', '0 30 7 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 6', '0 0 9 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 7', '0 30 10 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 8', '0 0 12 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 9', '0 30 13 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 10', '0 0 15 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 11', '0 30 16 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 12', '0 0 18 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 13', '0 30 19 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 14', '0 0 21 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 15', '0 30 22 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
System.schedule('TokenScheduler 16', '0 0 24 * * ?', new TokenScheduler());
```

Comment: I am getting error while executing your cron exprenssion System.StringException: Minute and Second values must be between 0 and 59

Comment: @Rene, I have edited my answer please check and confirm

Comment: can't it be done in one line. ? Please let me know. Also  I am getting this exception System.StringException: Hour values must be between 0 and 23.I tried replacing hour for the last one from 24 to 23, but it scheduled 5-6hrs late. I am in PST time.

Comment: It didn't help. It is scheduling multiple jobs.